# Why are these definitions of groups of central type equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, homology-cohomology, noncommutative-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group.

1. In the celebrated paper of Howlett and Isaacs, *On Groups of Central Type*, Math. Z. (1983)., the group $G$ is called to be of central type if $G$ has an irreducible complex character $\chi$ such that $\chi(1)^2=[G : Z(G)]$. (In other sources, the quotient $G/Z(G)$ is called to be of central type, where $G$ satisfies above property).
2. For each 2-cocycle $f \in Z^2(G, \mathbb{C}^*)$, a complex twisted group algebra, denoted by $\mathbb{C}^fG$, is defined by extending the multiplication $g_1.g_2:=f(g_1, g_2)g_1g_2$, $\forall g_1, g_2 \in G$, to all linear combinations of elements of $G$ with coeffecients in $\mathbb{C}$. It is known that complex twisted group algebra $\mathbb{C}^fG$ may be a simple ring. A group $G$ is called to be of central type, if the twisted complex group algebra $\mathbb{C}^f \overline{G}$ is simple for some $2$-cocyle $f$ on $\overline{G}$, where $\overline{G}=G/Z(G)$ . (For example see the [preprints of Ofir Schnabel](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2490) on this topic). 
    
     I know that $\mathbb{C}^fG$ is simple if and only if $G$ possesses only one class of irreducible $f$-projective character. But I can't see the relation of these two definitions. So my questions are as following: 
     **QUESTION 1:** How simplicity of $\mathbb{C}^f \overline{G}$ implies that $G$ is of central type according to the definition given in  $1$? (**Update:** this question is settled by the Theorem $1$ of [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01114468). The statement and proof of the theorem are given in answers).  
   **Further Discussions:**
   In the paper mentioned in $1$, the authors proved the following brilliant theorem:
   Theorem (Howlett-Isaacs): If $N \lhd G$ and $\lambda \in Irr(N)$ is a $G$-invariant irreducible character of $N$ such that ${\lambda}^G$ is a multiple of some $\chi \in Irr(G)$, then $G/N$ is solvable.

It is mentioned in [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870814000644) that if $\mathbb{C}^fG$ is simple, then Howlett-Isaacs theorem implies that $G$ is solvable.
[image]

 
**QUESTION 2:** Why the above claim is true?

 
 Thanks for any help.

Comment: In $Z^2(G,\mathbb{C}^*)$, do you assume that $G$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{C}^*$ ?

Comment: @CaptainLama According to http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2490 I would say yes. But generally, the action need not to be trivial (Ex. see the definition of Crossed Products in D. Passman books).

Comment: The thing is, the second definition seems to depend heavily on the choice of $f$. Is $G$ called of central type if $\mathbb{C}^f G$ is simple for all $f\in Z^2(G,\mathbb{C}^*)$ ?

Comment: No, it's obviously not true if $f$ is the trivial cocycle since then $\mathbb{C}^f G = \mathbb{C}[G]$ which is obviously not simple unless $G$ is trivial. So should it be "$\mathbb{C}^f G$ is simple for *some* $f\in Z^2(G,\mathbb{C}^*)$" ?

Comment: Off course not! If we choose $f=1$, then $\mathbb{C}^fG=\mathbb{C}G$ and the latter one is never simple since the augmentation ideal $\Delta(G) \neq 1$.

Comment: I see a third definition in the literature.  Indeed, does the intro [to this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.2516v1.pdf), including the references therein, cover your question, or not?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy  Thank you. According to the reference you provided, the irreducible $[\Gamma: Z(\Gamma)]$-dimensinal representation $V$ of $\Gamma$, determines a projective representation $\overline{V}$ of $G:={\Gamma}/Z(\Gamma)$ with some 2-cocycle $c$. We still need $\overline{V}$ to be the only equivalence class of irreducible $c$-projective representation of $G$ for $\mathbb{C}^cG$ to be simple. Unfortunately this is not covered in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Theorem $1$ of the following paper answers our question $1$.
 DeMeyer, F. R., Janusz, G.J. Finite groups with an irreducible representation of large degree. Math. Z. **108** (1969). 
[image]

**Answer to 2nd Question:** 
  Assume that $\mathbb{C}^fG$ is simple. Therefore, $G$ has an irreducible complex $f$-projective character $\chi$ such that ${\chi(1)}^2=|G|$. It is well known that $\chi$ determines an irreducible ordinary character $\chi^*$ of the same degree on $G^*$, where $G^*$ is a central extension of $G$ (namely a Schur cover of $G$).
  Now we have $G^*/C \cong G$ and ${\chi^*(1)}^2 = |G| = [G^* : C]$. Hence, $G^*$ is of central type (see definition 1). Restricting the character $\chi^*$ to $C$, we have ${\chi^*}_C = \chi^*(1) \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a linear character of $C$. Now ${\lambda}^{G^*}(1) = [G^* : C]$. On the other hand, $\chi^*(1) \chi^*$ is a constituent of ${\lambda}^{G^*}$. Comparing the degrees we obtain that ${\lambda}^{G^*} =\chi^*(1) \chi^* $. Now the Howlett-Isaacs theorem yields.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this is equivalent to your initial question : you get a 2-cocycle in $Z^2(G/Z(G),\mathbb{C}^*)$, which is is pretty easy ; what you asked was a cocycle in $Z^2(G,\mathbb{C}^*)$, and inflation will not give what you ask.

Comment: The probability that I didn't present my question in the most efficient way is not zero. However, This is actually what I wanted to know about the relation of simple twisted group algebras and their base groups.

Comment: Ok, then. You should probably edit your post for future readers to make it clear that in the definition "2" of groups of central type, you do not mean $G$ but $G/Z(G)$. And then make sure that Question 2 does not make the same confusion.

Comment: OK. The editions are done. Also an answer to the second question is found.